# Can I add permissions to media django media files?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I want to build an app and let user to see some videos just if they have permissions or they paid for that video. I am using Django and I want to add ngnix and gunicorn to serve media files.
I am not sure if once the user has the url of the video, how can I block him to not see the video if his payment expired or he doesn't have the permissions. For now I let django to serve the videos and I overwrite the server method and if he doesn't have access to video I return 404.

Comment: Instead of providing a static file directly , you should have your view dynamically serve files depending on the permissions of the user.

Comment: can you give me an short example please, I never used gunicorn and nginx, is my first time setting the production.

Comment: @lonewaft if I do how you said, the videos will come from nginx and will be server by django, can I make the videos seekable? Because now I can't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement the so-called 'X-Sendfile feature'. Let's say your paid-for files will be served from location `/protected/` - you need to add to nginx's config:

```
location /protected/ {
    internal;
    root   /some/path;
}
```

then when you want to serve your user a file named `mycoolflix.mp4` your app needs to add header `X-Accel-Redirect: /protected/mycoolflix.mp4` and the file `/some/path/protected/mycoolflix.mp4` will be served to the user. More information in the nginx documentation [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/) and [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/).
Serving files from your views is not a good idea - it makes one of your Django processes busy until the download is complete, preventing it from serving other requests.